# How to pass the NSTimer as parameter in function in SpriteKit swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, swift2

I have a simple function to move my sprite for predefine time duration. I want that the time duration which i pass in to function as time duration is passing in function parameter as NSTimer. My function is as below!

```
func moveGooses(){
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:self.parentScene.frame.width*0.99  , y:   self.parentScene.frame.height*0.90))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint( x:self.parentScene.frame.width*0.01  , y:   self.parentScene.frame.height*0.90), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: self.parentScene.frame.width*0.01, y: self.parentScene.frame.height*0.90) , controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: self.parentScene.frame.width*0.01  , y:   self.parentScene.frame.height*0.90))
    let anim            = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 3.0)
    let seq             = SKAction.sequence([anim])
    let removeAction    = SKAction.runBlock{
        let myGameScene =   self.parentScene as GameScene
        self.removeFromParent()
    }
    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([seq,removeAction]))
}
```

Comment: Could we also see the code where you create the NSTimer please?

Comment: The sentence "I want that the time duration which i pass in to function as time duration is passing in function parameter as NSTimer. " makes no sense to me. Please clarify.

Comment: I have a function of spritenode move. In that function i have a path. The path is moving from one side to another for specific duration. As above the duration is 0.3 second. I just need the duration which i pass in to function. Out side the function dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague but I believe this is what you're trying to do according to question title:

```
func timerAsParam(timer: NSTimer) {
    //timer is a local nstimer
}
```